# Ecology data question - should you exclude a dominant species from PCA?

Tags: pca

I am a diatomist and collect species abundance data. In my particular field, it is common to count a certain number of species (say 500 for example) and then to recount the same number excluding a particular species (call it species y) because the abundance of species y is commonly 70 - 95% of the overall assemblage. So I get the reasoning behind doing a species y-free recount, in order to pull out trends in the less abundant species (this is time series data btw) which would otherwise be masked by the dominance of species y.

PCA is then carried out on the species y-free recount data, thus excluding species y from any statistical analysis. However, the abundance of species y in the first count (which includes species y) is often plotted and used in the overall interpretation of assemblage when putting a story together. I hope all that makes sense.

My question is, what effect does the exclusion of the dominant species have on the PCA? If the abundance of the species is used in the interpretation, should it not be included in the PCA, but with a square root transformation to take the dominance into account? This is just the done thing in the field (geologists do not make the best statisticians, I feel like I can say that as a geologist), but I can't help but wonder what effect the exclusion of such a dominant species would have on the eigenvectors etc., especially if we go on to use its abundance later. Do you know what I mean?

If any statisticians out there have any comments, I gladly welcome them. Thanks

Comment: It's not clear to me what the PCA is being done on .